# project problem

Tags: projects-and-solutions

can anybody suggest me how i casn create an application or web application for saving mobile data and get backup/recover when sombody lost that mobile phone...............
till i only know about microsoft synchronization framework a little but problem is that from where to start

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need to have some sort of webservice to which data to be backed up can be sent, and you would need some way of retrieving that data when restoring from a backup. You will need to have a way to ensure that this is done securely (you can only retrieve data that you backed up), and you will need to have some way to make it reliable (data is safe when backed up, you know when regularly scheduled backups have not occurred and can diagnose the problem or reschedule the next backup sooner, etc.).

You will need to decide which phones you are supporting, what versions of those phones, what type of user data on those phones you wish to backup, etc. You will probably also need to know a ballpark number of how many phones you intend to backup (which should affect how much storage you need).

The place to start is a clear set of requirements. A particular framework is an implementation detail that is only useful to know about and can only be evaluated once the requirements are completely clear.